# WCF with Entity Framework multiple tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf

I am creating a WCF service which is using Entity Framework for communication with SQL 2012 server. I have 3 questions.
1. Is is possible to create the database from VS2013 like in MVC5 models?
3. From where I can reach a good information except codeproject since there, they work only with one table and no relations at all.
I am a bit confused since I was get use to work with MVC and there everything is quite clear to me. Here I made simple exmplate, but I created the DB first and then the WCF + EF and the test Web Form application.

edited to not violate requirements

Comment: Welcome to SO!  To answer your first question yes it is possible to do CodeFirst within Visual Studio as this doesn't depend on WCF, but instead has to do with Entity Framework.  Your other two questions violate allowed questions on StackOverflow, since you cannot ask for tutorials: [see this article on allowed questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  If you have specific questions, especially with supporting code you'll get lots of help here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's too broad a question to answer easily but "Pro C# 5.0 and the .NET 4.5 Framework" by Andrew Troelson has several chapters dedicated to the Entity Framework, WCF, and working with them. That would be your best bet for a high quality "tutorial" of sorts. It's my go-to reference text for C# and .NET and so far it has proven extremely useful during my programming internship.